# Android: Bitmap size in memory

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using a Nexus 5X emulator with a density of 420 dpi and screen size of 1080x1920 px. I load an original size bitmap into an ImageView. On disk, the bitmap's size is 1.3 MB and 1280x851 px. 
My ImageView dimensions are width: full screen, height: full screen. My image has a 32-bit color depth = 4 bytes per pixel. I calculated the expected size in memory as 1080x1920x4=8.29 MB.

When I run my code and load my image, it's size in memory is approximately 30MB. What is the reason for that and how can I adjust my calculations in order to get the right estimation? I am of course aware methods to load a downscaled image into a small container but I try to figure out how to calculate the size of the full image.

Thanks

Comment: "On disk" -- where precisely do you have this file in your project? Or are you loading the image via some other means (e.g., from a file, from a Web URL)?

Comment: Inside the drawable folder.I know that it's better to avoid high-resolution images inside the drawable folders but I am trying to find the right calculation. I am loading the image via setImageResource(resId)

Answer (score 9):

> I calculated the expected size in memory as 1080x1920x4=8.29 MB.

The screen size does not matter here.

`res/drawable/` is an old synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. You are indicating that your image is designed for `-mdpi` devices (~160 dpi), and that it should be up-sampled for higher-density devices (and down-sampled for `-ldpi` devices).

A Nexus 5X is classified as an `-xxhdpi` device (~480 dpi). This means that each pixel of your original image should be mapped into 9 pixels in the up-sampled image (480 / 160 = 3 on each axis). 1280 x 851 = 1089280 pixels * 9 scaling factor * 4 bytes/pixel = 39214080 bytes = 37.4MB.

Comment: Thanks!! You help me a lot

Comment: my bitmaop size comes to h: 3024 and w:4032, in galaxy edge 7, does that mean it is 3024*4032*4 bytes ?

Comment: @AalapPatel: Yes.

Comment: How can I calculate Bitmap size in memory while loading images from a Url using Picasso or Glide or any other image loading library?  @CommonsWare

Comment: @RohitSingh: In general, the same resolution-based calculation applies. However, for any given URL, it will depend on what the initial image resolution is, what transformations might get applied by the library (e.g., cropping, scaling), etc.

Comment: Is there any method that I can use to calculate the memory size of a Bitmap? for eg bitmap.getByteCount() . @CommonsWare

Comment: @RohitSingh: I would use `getAllocationByteCount()` on API Level 19+. But otherwise, yes, given a `Bitmap`, that is how you determine how much heap space it consumes. Sorry, I did not realize that you were referring to having an actual `Bitmap` object in your previous comment.